# Default values for Vue prop type "Object"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Object or array defaults must be returned from a factory function ([source](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-validation)).

Example:

```
foobar: {
  type: Object,
  default() {
    return {}
  }
}

// OR

foobar: {
  type: Object,
  default: () => ({})
}
```

`foobar` will return an empty object `{}` by default.

But if you want to know if it is defined, it will always return "true". So you can do this instead:

```
foobar: {
  type: Object,
  default() {}
}

// OR

foobar: {
  type: Object,
  default: () => {}
}
```

`foobar` will return as `undefined` by default.

Is that last practice naughty?

Comment: It certainly isn't intuitive.  It's probably more important that the object be "non-empty" than "defined", in which case, `Object.keys(foobar).length > 0` is an adequate check.

Comment: If it's supposed to be uninitialized then null is semantically correct default value. Though undefined will work too

Comment: @EstusFlask, as in `default: null`?

Comment: @ckhatton Yes, like that

Answer (score 1):

You can check an object for definition by counting its keys:

```
Object.keys(foobar).length > 0 // true when it is filled
```

Or by using JSON's stringify method:

```
JSON.stringify(foobar) !== '{}' // true when it is filled
```

There are many other approaches to check for an object's emptiness. The [reference topic](https://sentry.io/answers/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object/).

Answer (score 0):

As @EstusFlask comments; instead of it invoking an empty function (`default: () => {}` i.e. `(() => {})()`) that returns `undefined`, you might as well just assign the default as `undefined` or `null` like so:

```
foobar: {
  type: Object,
  default: null
}
```

`foobar` will return as `null` by default.